# Erro na conversão String para Double

Tags: java, android

Cenário:

```
public void metodoX(Double valor) {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    String valorRound = df.format(valor);
    Double valorRound2 = Double.parseDouble(valorRound);
    ...
}
```

Erro:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "3,67"
```

Linha com erro:

```
Double valorRound2 = Double.parseDouble(valorRound);
```

Detalhes:

O app está `rodando perfeitamente no emulador API 23`, mas rodando no `celular API 23, causa esse erro`.

Por que só no celular dá o erro ?

Já tentei:

```
Double valorRound2 = Double.valueOf(valorRound);
```

Comment: Ele está esperando um valor com `.` para separador decimal, não vírgula. Não sei porque ele produz essa vírgula pois aparentemente o formato decimal deveria ser com `.` ; uma das causas prováveis é que o emulador está com locale inglês e o aparelho português

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado entendi, pode ser locale... você acha que com o bigdecimal, daria para resolver ?

Comment: Se você não estiver em aplicações científicas, nem sei porque usar `double` para começo de conversa. Eu usaria sempre `BigDecimal`. Tem uma pergunta muito interessante sobre o assunto, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Então basicamente melhor usar o `BigDecimal` para todos os casos que não precisam ser flutuantes (acredito que 99% não precisamos de mais de 4 casas depois da vírgula) !? Aproveitando, o BigDecimal já contém limitação de casas ?

Comment: Usar o BigDecimal não irá resolver o `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: A precisão é arbitrária. Eu trabalho com 30 para me garantir no cálculo de impostos (mesmo o usuário informando no máximo 2 casas decimais de valor, 4 casas do que temos armazenado na tabela de impostos e 4 casas no desconto da venda do produto). Eu creio que seu caso seja de precisão arbitrária. Isso não vai evitar os problemas de formatação, como o @ramaral  apontou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Por que só no celular dá o erro ?

Dá erro num e não no outro porque o separador decimal depende do *Locale* definido no dispositivo. Nalguns é `.`, em outros é `,`.

Suponho que esse valor é introduzido pelo utilizador, assim tem de garantir que ele é introduzido no formato correcto.

Uma das formas possíveis de o fazer é indicar `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` na declaração do EditText:

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edittext"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="0" 
   android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

Edição após comentário:

> Não é no input não, é de um SeekBar com variação 0.01(...)

Nesse caso faça assim:

```
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

String valorRound = df.format(valor);
Double valorRound2 = Double.parseDouble(valorRound);
```

Comment: Não é no input não, é de um SeekBar com variação 0.01 ! Mas não conhecia essa, já é outra nova ! Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

## Explicação

Você está tendo uma exceção por algum motivo, portanto em uma situação que pode haver exeções, deve-se tratar as exceções com bloco de `try/catch`.

## Códigos

Resultando desta forma:

```
public void metodoX(Double valor) {

  try {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    String valorRound = df.format(new Double(valor));
    Double valorRound2 = Double.parseDouble(valorRound);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    valor = 0; //valor padrão
  }
  ...
}
```

Porém, o problema em questão aparentemente é com o Locale e suas diferenças de tratamento de Doubles entre `,` e `.`, por isso eu recomendaria utilizar um  `DecimalFormatSymbols` para evitar problemas com vírgula, desta forma:

```
Locale meuLocale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DecimalFormatSymbols simbolos = new DecimalFormatSymbols(meuLocale);
simbolos.setDecimalSeparator(',');
simbolos.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(valor, simbolos);
```

> (de acordo com o comentário de @Jefferson Quesado, provavelmente o locale é a causa da divergência de funcionamento, portanto aplicar este último bloco de código iria resolver.)

Comment: Reveja o que é dito na primeira parte da resposta porque não faz qualquer sentido.

Comment: Não teria problema usar o Locale, mas forçar o ptBR aí não seria bacana. Preciso estudar como puxar, etc etc... então acho mais fácil correr para o BigDecimal e aprende-lo melhor já que praticamente vou usar no lugar do Double. Mas agradeço a ideia, sempre aprendendo ! Obrigado !